# Display android number keypad on right

Tags: android, keyboard, numpad

I have a layout that has a listview on the left side, what I would like to do is have the Android keypad display on the right side on load. I have created a custom keypad but wondering if there is a way to use the Android number pad.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't change keyboard position.

Comment: IS there any other way to do this?